# Trouble installing WiFi driver on HP Spectre x360 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, laptop

I dual-booted Ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows 10-running HP Spectre x360, but haven't been able to get the WiFi driver to work. Here is what I tried:

1) Plugged in an Ethernet cable and checked if it comes up under "Additional Drivers".

2) Ran lspci -vnnk | grep -A2 0280 to find that my network controller chipset is an **Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fd] (rev 78)** with **subsystem [8086:1010]**.

3) Ran rfkill list to check if it was blacklisted. Here, only my Bluetooth appeared, so the Wireless LAN doesn't even come up.

4) Ran iwconfig, only output was **lo:  no wireless extensions**.

5) Researched drivers, found on [this site](http://listing.driveragent.com/c/pci/8086/24fd?PHPSESSID=9uaan9d1iv3r22ob1sgc82c250&PHPSESSID=9uaan9d1iv3r22ob1sgc82c250) that my driver should be an Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8275.
** EDIT: Checked Windows Device manager from my Windows boot and it's actually **Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265**

6) Went to the [Intel support website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) for Linux drivers and copied the .tgz file into /lib/firmware. I'm not sure if that was supposed to be Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8275.enough to do the trick, but I'm also not sure it's the correct driver at all. I think it isn't the correct one though, because I found the [same instructions](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) on the Linux wireless wiki.

7) Found [this repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) of Linux wireless firmware, but I found the interface really confusing.

What is the driver file actually supposed to look like? Is it the same thing as firmware?

I would appreciate any help, as I am truly at my wit's end!

---

Edit 1:
Adding output for `sudo lshw -c Network -sanitize`

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc100000-dc101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx00249b239219
       serial: [REMOVED]
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.08.2 duplex=full ip=[REMOVED] link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

Comment: (1) Add the output of the following to your question: `sudo lshw -c Network -sanitize`.

(2) Also, towards the bottom of this output, find the driver name from "driver=<driver>".  Using this, run the command, `modinfo <driver> | head -10`, and add the output of that command to your question as well.

Comment: @PJSingh Updated. It doesn't seem like anything is configured for the network controller.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you downloaded the file [iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz) to your Downloads folder, open a terminal window and execute the following...

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo tar --directory=/lib/firmware/ -xvf iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0/iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode --strip=1
```

This will extract `iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode` and place it in your `/lib/firmware/` folder.

Then restart your computer and see if your wireless works.

Comment: Note: Xenial (16.04) does not contain a driver for the Intel 8265 wireless adapter, but Artful (17.10) does. Instead of using the downloaded driver from Intel, it may be worthwhile to install the driver from Artful, or to simply upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. Here are the drivers for Xenial: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=iwlwifi&mode=filename&suite=xenial&arch=any.  Here are the drivers for Artful: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=iwlwifi&mode=filename&suite=artful&arch=any

Comment: Those are the firmware files, not the driver.

Comment: @chili555, Thx.  Didn't know what to call them!

Comment: I recommend that you simply upgrade to either 17.04 or 17.10. Run the live session USB and confirm that everything works as expected and install.